# Is there a software solution that could enable me to use Gmail via an internet connection that is too slow for standard Gmail, HTML version is going

Tags: gmail

**Question**
Is there a software solution that could enable me to use Gmail via an internet connection that is to slow for standard Gmail, now that the Gmail-HTML-version will no longer be available in early 2024?

- An idea that I would be interested in would be for me to use TTY to access Gmail via a Message-Relay-Service, but I have no idea how to use TTY on my laptop (I know nothing about TTY), and I have no idea about Message-Relay-Services, since I assume they are private is it really wise to use them (in regards to security and privacy).
- Another idea would be to use a Microsoft-Email-Account, which seems to be able to fully use Gmail email addresses, and seems to allow full access to the Gmail-Inbox of the Gmail account, etc, etc,  however, my slow internet connection makes accessing that even more impossible.
  There is a lite version of Microsoft-Email-Accounts somewhere, but I think that that cannot be accessed without installing the APP for Microsoft-Email-Account, an option I just don't want to do due to important reasons.

Comment: For very slow network connections I would try to use a dedicated e-mail client and use POP3+SMTP. Unfortunately TLS compression is for security reasons usually not available (for mails this would be very helpful for you). Most mail client can use POP3 to load only message subject lines and only load the remaining part on demand when you really want to read it's content.